# get next 12 weeks of fridays

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, loops, date

I am currently doing this:

```
x = Date.today
y = x + 12.weeks
(x..y).each do |date|
  next unless date.strftime("%A") == 'Friday'
  @dates << date
end
```

There has to be better code to do this, can anyone give it to me or give me the right thing to look for to find how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice one-liner: `(Date.today..Date.today + 12.weeks).select(&:friday?)` - Voila!

Comment: In what version of rails is friday? defined?

Comment: Sorry don't know, but it's definitely in Rails 3, and the question is tagged as Rails 3, so I'm sure it will work.

Comment: new in 3.1?   it's not in 3.0.7 . . .  I know monday is an alias for beginning_of_week, but I've never seen monday? (or friday?)

Comment: It works fine on my system(3.0.4). Its elegant, but mechanics and processing wise would be much similar to OP's code. Better way can be `nearest_friday = (Date.today..Date.today + 6.days).select(&:friday?); @dates = (0...12).map{|i| nearest_friday + i.weeks }`

Answer (score 1):

```
  x = Date.today
  x += 1.day while x.wday < 5
  @dates = (0...12).map{|i| x+i.weeks}
```